# Warnings of brew cleanup

Tags: homebrew

I got the following warnings when I did `brew cleanup`. How can I fix them?

```
$ brew cleanup
Warning: Skipping ant: most recent version 1.9.7 not installed
Warning: Skipping atk: most recent version 2.20.0 not installed
...
(continued)
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a nondeterministic bug when a formula is built from source using:

`brew install {{formula}} --HEAD`

Messages like this:

```
Warning: Skipping llvm: most recent version 3.8.1 not installed
Warning: Skipping tidy-html5: most recent version 5.2.0 not installed
```

`brew doctor` can't fix this because it looks like some version finder code is trying to load the version number for HEAD formulas and indicating confusion.

Submit a minimal bug to the [brew issue tracker](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew) which reproduces it consistently (using a small, quick-building, stable package).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you only need to update to the latest version,

```
brew upgrade ant
```

and

```
brew upgrade atk
```

*In your example

If it doesn't work, check how to update the version to the relevant package